# HTML DOM innerHTML Property

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Change the HTML content of a `<p>` element with `id="demo"`:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!";
```

**is this right way to change the html content?**

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: it's working fine i just want to know is that right way to use innerHTML

Comment: @epascarello OP wanted to know if it's the right way, you can do many things with let's say `eval` but it doesn't mean that you should

Comment: ok thank you @pwoloaq

Comment: Is it the right way. It might be, it might not be. All depends on what you are doing. In your simple test case it is fine. Might make more sense to use textContent if you have no HTML mark-up. Read [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

Comment: yes, it's the right way

Comment: You shouldn't view your methodology with such a binary definition

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change only contents use

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerText = "Paragraph changed!";
```

Or you want to change html tags also use,

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML  = "<h2>Heading changed!</h2>";
```

Another method

```
document.getElementById("demo").firstChild.nodeValue = "Paragraph changed!";
```

Answer (score 0):

As [MDN says:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

> This property provides a simple way to completely replace the contents of an element.

Answer (score 0):

```
In this syntax example, {ID of element} is the ID of an HTML element and {content} is the new content to go into the element.
document.getElementById('{ID of element}').innerHTML = '{content}';

Now for your Issue,just do this
document.getElementsByTagName("P")[0].innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!"; [OR] document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!";
```

[FiddleLink](https://jsfiddle.net/za0zabfL/)